# Trying to check if an email with the same value already exists

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make so it checks if the email already exists in the database before inserting the data in it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "servername";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    $Mail = $_POST['email'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    //Inputed in E-Mail Field
    $Mail = $_POST['email'];

    $SearchEmail = $conn->query("SELECT (Mail) FROM betakey WHERE Mail = '$Mail'");

    if ($SearchEmail->num_rows > 0) {
        print "That Email is already registered for the closed alpha";
    }
    else {
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO betakey VALUES ('$Mail')");
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

It doesn't give me any error when i access the page but it also doesn't echo that it exists or inserts the data when it doesn't.

Comment: Can you try this: "SELECT count(Mail) FROM betakey WHERE Mail = '$Mail'"

Comment: you might want to add an `echo 'mail sent';`  statement before the last brace in your code to help you with debugging.

Comment: enabling error_log to a single file and post it, you may have a sql or php syntax error.

Comment: ahmet still didn't work, Mike, done.

Comment: Pat4561 is right. I thought that the problem is detecting whether the mail exists or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Check if row exists before inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225765/php-check-if-row-exists-before-inserting)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your insert query. An insert query is always structured like shown below.

INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
See: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Applying this to your code, results in the following.

```
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$Mail = $_POST['email'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Inputed in E-Mail Field
$Mail = $_POST['email'];

$SearchEmail = $conn->query("SELECT count(Mail) FROM betakey WHERE Mail = '$Mail'");

if ($SearchEmail->num_rows > 0) {
    print "That Email is already registered for the closed alpha";
}
else {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO betakey (Mail) VALUES ('$Mail')");
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

And I suggest you take away one of the two '$Mail = $_POST['email'];', because it is useless to declare a variable twice in the same way.

Comment: I don't think thats the answer for it since i tried to register an email that already existed and it didn't give me the "print "(...)" statement.

Comment: What is the output of $SearchEmail when you try to print it?

Comment: ahmet, this happens 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /home/a9508844/public_html/BetaRegistration.php on line 31 Thats probably why it isnt working but how do i fix it

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at php but maybe you can try to print as in the answer of @mailo ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157905/mysql-query-result-in-php-variable )

Comment: @KillZoneZ, no, the fatal error happens because you try to print an array. If you want to see the output you should use the print_r($array) funtion. Could you provide us with the full code? At my side it is working when I try to register an email that already exists, so it should work at your side too.